# Flink RocksDB not creating sst files in taskmanager

Tags: scala, apache-flink, rocksdb

I am using flink-1.4.2 with scala and RocksDB is used for state backend but I am not getting sst files in taskmanager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set `state.backend.rocksdb.localdir`? If not, the SST files will be stored wherever `io.tmp.dirs` points to, which defaults to `/tmp` in Linux systems.

Comment: Hi David, I have not set state.backend.rocksdb.localdir and so, I have checked /tmp but I do not get any sst files

Comment: I would then want to see how you have configured RocksDB to be the state backend, and also verify that your job has state that can be stored in RocksDB. Keep in mind that non-keyed state is never stored in RocksDB, and by default timers are also on-heap.

Comment: env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("file:///mnt/flink_rocks/checkpoints", false))

Comment: I have used this code to set Rocksdb as state backend

Comment: We are storing state as key because I am calculating median on that particular key.

Comment: Seems like it should work. Have you checked the taskmanager log files?

Comment: Hi David, after 2 days, now, I can see the sst. Is this normal or is there any issue in my setup

Comment: I don’t know what RocksDB does in cases where the state and update rate are small enough that the disk isn’t needed.